# How to remove a xml node using condition based on element

Tags: xml, xslt

@Yitzhak. Thank you so much for the answers. I'd like to update my full XSLT file and I hope you can continue to help
I have below xml file and I'd like to ask how can I remove the entire `<MaterialCallOff>` node based on condition that element PlantCode=2001 using XSLT ?

The current XSLT is below but it did not work

```
--Deleted due to company regulation violation
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XSLT.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MaterialCallOff[PlantCode='2001' and Workplace='3092_GACH08S1']">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Testing xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <WholeInfo>
    <MaterialCallOff>
      <PlantCode>3092</PlantCode>
      <PartNumber>BIW40002871</PartNumber>
      <CallType>Automatic</CallType>
      <Quantity>16</Quantity>
      <UOM>EA</UOM>
      <Workplace>3092_GACH08S1</Workplace>
    </MaterialCallOff>
    <MaterialCallOff>
      <PlantCode>3092</PlantCode>
      <PartNumber>BIW40002872</PartNumber>
      <CallType>Automatic</CallType>
      <Quantity>14</Quantity>
      <UOM>EA</UOM>
      <Workplace>3092_GACH08S1</Workplace>
    </MaterialCallOff>
  </WholeInfo>
</Testing>
```

Comment: Great Yitzhak, This is what exactly I looking for. But another question, how can I add 2 conditions into this. For ex, PlantCode=2001 and workplace=3092_GACH08S1

Comment: @TienThanh, I updated the answer with the 2nd condition. Check it out.

Comment: Hope you can see my comment @Yitzhak

Comment: I think @YitzhakKhabinsky has made a mistake by telling you the answer rather than explaining what you did wrong and letting you find the answer by yourself. Rather than immediately coming back with supplementary questions, try to understand the code that Yiitzhak has written, read up on the language constructs so you understand how it works, and learn a bit more about XSLT rather than asking other people to do your work for you.

Comment: In addition, please note that changing a question after it has been answered is generally bad form, because it makes things very difficult for subsequent visitors to understand. Adding supplementary information is fine if it is clearly labelled as such, but you should never edit a question "in situ" in such a way as to invalidate an existing answer. Better to start again with a new question.

Comment: Totally agree @Michael. I found the way to fix my issue based on advise from Yitzshak. 
I take forum rules seriously and will revert to the original question